# JSOUP Automatically Login to a website

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

I am trying to parse a website which requires login. From browser, when I do login at the login page(https://backoffice.holidayinsider.com/backoffice2/login), I am automatically redirected to https://backoffice.holidayinsider.com/backoffice2/login.

So first of all I am trying to automate the login using Java. My approach is motivated by this [stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289037/jsoup-how-to-crawl-a-login-required-page-using-jsoup). The code I am using is the following:

```
package Login;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
public class DoLogin {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try {

            Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://backoffice.holidayinsider.com/backoffice2/login")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

            Connection.Response mainPage = Jsoup.connect("https://backoffice.holidayinsider.com/backoffice2")
                .data("username", "myusername")
                .data("password", "mypass")
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies()).execute();
            System.out.println(mainPage.parse());

            Map<String, String> cookies = mainPage.cookies();

            Document evaluationPage = Jsoup.connect("https://backoffice.holidayinsider.com/backoffice2/")
                .cookies(cookies)
                .execute().parse();
            System.out.println(evaluationPage);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems the login is working as status code is 200. Now the problem is when I print mainPage, it seems it is still at login page. What can be the reason? Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

While your login you need to add POST method :

```
        Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://backoffice.holidayinsider.com/backoffice2/login")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute(); 

        Connection.Response mainPage = Jsoup.connect("https://backoffice.holidayinsider.com/backoffice2/login")
            .data("username", "myusername") 
            .data("password", "mypass") 
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .followRedirects(true)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST).execute(); 
        System.out.println(mainPage.parse());

        Map<String, String> cookies = mainPage.cookies();

        Document evaluationPage = Jsoup.connect("https://backoffice.holidayinsider.com/backoffice2/")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .get();
        System.out.println(evaluationPage);
```